# Form reset functionality in angular 5

Tags: angular, forms

I'm serving value as fast as I can when user submitted current value. In this case after submitting current value I'm resetting the form and serving new value to user. It working as `async` call `form.reset` execution completes after serving new value so at the end my user get null/empty value.

Is there any alternative ways to achieve this or any chances of making it `sync`

code:
`.ts`

```
     @ViewChild('f') form

     ngOnInit() {
       this.initialCall();
     }

     initialCall() {
       this.name = 'Angular 5';
     }

     onSubmit(){
       this.form.reset(); //reset form
       this.initialCall(); //serve next value
     }
```

`.html`

```
<form  #f="ngForm"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" name="initail">
  <button type="submit">Done</button>
</form>
```

What I'm expecting is after click on `Done` button I need to show  'Angular 5' in text field but it showing empty.

And do any one can explain why change detection not happening here ?

Comment: i don't get what you mean if you console name in ```onSubmit``` you get the name.

Comment: @fatemefazli I just edited my question, let me know still you need any info/clarification.

Comment: your code works fine, when i click on done input is Angular 5 and name var is full.

Comment: but binding not happening once check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found using [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef), 
and it's work like a charm!

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild , ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string;
  @ViewChild('f') form
  ngOnInit() {
    this.InitialCall();
  }
  constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef){}
  InitialCall() {
    this.name = 'Angular 5';
  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.form.reset();
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.InitialCall(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: why I need to call `changeDetector` manually ? why it not detecting changes on form.reset() ?

Comment: @k11k2 When you clear the form value but then immediately restore the value that was already in the UI before change detection runs, change detection will not see any change and doesn't update the binding.

Comment: okay, form.reset() - `changeDetector` pending, binding - `change detection`completed(current and previous same), form.reset() - `changeDetector` completed. so it results empty. then If I bind different value then change detector works normal in this case how `changeDetector` works ? any well defined blogs on this topic?

Comment: @k11k2 yes. check this [blog](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f) and [Angular.io](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef).

Answer (score 5):

You can use,

```
onSubmit(){
    this.form.form.markAsPristine();
    this.form.form.markAsUntouched();
    this.form.form.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

**Here is the code:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string;
  @ViewChild('f') form
  ngOnInit() {

    this.InitialCall();
  }
  InitialCall() {
    this.name = 'Angular 5';
  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.form.form.markAsPristine();
    this.form.form.markAsUntouched();
    this.form.form.updateValueAndValidity();

    this.InitialCall(); 
  }
}
```

[**Here is a DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rdnuex?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: `form.reset` will set my form to initial state like set all validations states to normal so I'm using `form.reset`. is there any other way to set form to normal/initial state ?

Comment: @k11k2, have you seen the latest code, It achieves your requirement, `validations` and everything will get `reset`

Comment: yes, but I'm not achieving my goal by using this. do you have any idea why `form.reset()` not detecting changes ?

Comment: `form.reset()` is taking some time to `respond`

Answer (score 0):

Update `onSubmit` method as:

```
onSubmit(){
    this.form.reset();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.InitialCall(); 
    }, 1)
}
```

You will have to use `setTimeout`

Comment: why `1` (which was `10` before the edit) specifically?

Comment: You can make it `0`, it's just to change the calling sequence.

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal `setTimeOut` is not in our option mate. cause our main goal is to serve new value as fast as we can.

Comment: @k11k2 the time specified is in millis so I think it won't effect if you set it `0`, it just invoke the method defined within it after finishing first statement on main thread.

Comment: @k11k2 setTimeout() doesn't halt the execution of the script during the timeout period; it merely schedules the specified expression to be run at the specified time. After the call to setTimeout() the script continues normally, with the timer running in the background.

Answer (score -1):

You should use reactive-form approach for the form, because this is very easy to maintain validation and controls of form.
And by using reactive-form approach you can use patchValue or setValue method of reactive form.

Comment: you mean `REACTIVE FORMS` ?

Comment: we stick to template-driven forms