# custom pipe is not working when using form.reset();

Tags: javascript, angular

when using Form.reset() to reset the form. custom pipe not transforming the values.

I am resetting the form data.

```
Form.reset(Object);

<input type="text" [ngModel]="object.STATUSTS | localTimestamp" readonly>
```

It is working in initial component binding.

Please find code file https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nymzmd

Comment: are you reseting form or object data?

Comment: I am resetting the form data.

Comment: Please add some more sample code to work with. It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can use [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to create one.

Comment: @SiddAjmera  Please find the link [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nymzmd]

Comment: Your link is dead.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nymzmd

Comment: Does this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50810561/form-reset-functionality-in-angular-5 - help ?

Comment: No, I updated the code with suggested answer not working. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nymzmd

Comment: i think you are mixing things up, you are assigning to a ``variable object`` the statusts, if you update that variable then the pipe will work just fine ex: ``object.STATUSTS = UnModifiedobject.STATUSTS ``, and using a @ViewChild on the form wich is not related to the binding you've made with object.STATUSTS. If you wish to use the forms functions you will have to take a look at reactive forms